# AWS EMR user access information?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-cli, amazon-emr

After setting up the EMR cluster in AWS is there a way to retrieve information about the user, who created the cluster?

I checked under the cluster details, logs and trail but couldn't find the information. Is there a CLI command that we can use to extract the user /owner information of the EMR cluster?

Comment: So there isn't a way to get the user info ?

Comment: Did you check CloudTrail logs?

Answer (score 1):

One can see the details of who created EMR(and many more) in the service CloudTrail.

Steps:

- CloudTrail --> Event histroy
- First filter box : "Lookup attributes" select "Event name"
- Second filter box : give "RunJobFlow"
- Third filter: select the data range, when the cluster was created(this can be obtained from service EMR-->Clusters)

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/logging_emr_api_calls.html

[image]